# "timeRemaining is not defined" error

Tags: python, robotics, myro, calico-project

I'm taking a robotics course and I imported the Myro library in Calico.  timeRemaining is supposed to be a predefined function in the Myro library but it keeps saying it's undefined.

There's an online handbook for Myro functions and even this does not work:

```
while timeRemaining(5):
print "running..."
```

This is the exact error

```
NameError: name 'timeRemaining' is not defined
```

I'm even copying code directly from the book and it's saying `timeRemaining` isn't defined.  The code from the book is supposed to work.

Other predefined functions like `turnLeft`, `forward(speed, time)`, etc. work, but `timeRemaining` does not.

Here's code right from the Calico book `Learning Computing With Robots`

```
def main():
    # Run the robot for 60 seconds
    while timeRemaining(60):
        L, C, R = getLight()
        # motors run proportional to light
        motors(normalize(L), normalize(R))
stop()
```

When I try to run `main()` it does not work.  It says timeRemaining is undefined.   I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Did you `import myro`? Easiest would be `from myro import *`

Comment: is timer() defined?  for seconds in timer(5): print "running for", seconds, "..."

Comment: Yes, I imported Myro.   That's how I did it 'from Myro import*'   Says it's undefined.

Comment: Yes, timer() worked.                                                I wrote while timer(60): print("hello")  and it printed "hello" for 60 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of myro are you using?

Taking a look [here](http://myro.roboteducation.org/download/), I can see `timeRemaining` defined in `__init__.py`, which is imported when you run `from myro import *`. Some of the older versions do not have this function, so make sure you are running the latest version first.

Comment: I am running the latest version for mac.  I believe it's 3.1

Comment: Also, when I do the 'senses' function it says my light is 65000, but in the book it says it should max at 5000

Comment: Konercny, my teacher gave me this link.  The latest version for Macs is 3.1.  Are you suggesting I download an older version?   http://myro.roboteducation.org/~dblank/download/?C=N;O=D;P=*-mac*.zip

Comment: Oh.. I have the latest version of Calico, but not the latest version of Myro it seems.  How do I install it, just click the .py file?

Comment: It appears I have 2.8 as that is what was recommended on the website.  I don't know how to put the 2.9 into the python path on Macs.